# Junit instance creation each by method or class

Tags: java, junit, nunit

Recently, I'm reading the book `Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests` and I'm confused about the description they say of Junit behaviour.

If I understand what the authors say, Junit creates a new instance of a test class and in each test method to ensure they are isolated from each other.

> To run a test, JUnit creates a new instance of the test class and
>   calls the relevant test method. Creating a new test object each time
>   ensures that the tests are isolated from each other, because the test
>   object’s fields are replaced before each test. This means that a test
>   is free to change the contents of any of the test object fields.

Then they say that in NUnit (.Net) is different, because it reuses the same test object for all test methods, so you need to reset the objects using `Setups` and `TearDowns`.

> NUnit Behaves Differently from JUnit Those working in `.Net` should note
>   that NUnit reuses the same instance of the test object for all the
>   test methods, so any values that might change must either be reset in
>   [Setup] and [TearDown] methods (if they’re fields) or made local to
>   the test method.

I though JUnit behaves just as they describe the NUnit behaviour, so your class instances are reusable in the same class and you use Setups and TearDown to reset them.

So, how JUnit behaves, it instantiates the test class in each method or otherwise it instantitates the test class once.

Maybe I don't understand what the authors mean. What they mean?

Comment: The description is correct, JUnit creates a new object for each test.  Try it yourself.

Comment: And the description of NUnit is correct as well. Different software, for different platforms, written by different people, with different visions. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JUnit instantiates the test class for each test (aka method annotated with `@Test`).

The setup and teardown methods are there only to help you writing clear and easy to read test - by extracting common setup of test environment, preconditions and verifications so it doesn't mess up the test itself.

1. The environment setup is *static* and can be shared accros all tests in the class - it's ok to create it only once - the `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` annotations (note that the methods must be static)
2. The environment setup is specific for each test and can't be shared accros all tests in the class - the `@Before` and `@After` annotations